# How to only count duplicates in the same index position between 2 list?

Tags: python-3.x

I have 3 list, I want to only count duplicates in same index position

```
#list example
a = [11,22]
b = [33,22]
c = [22,11]
```

Using a as reference and comparing b and c to a

b and a have duplicates in index position [1] so count 1 duplicate

```
[11,22],[33,22]
```

c and a have 2 duplicates but they are in different index position so count 0

```
[11,22],[22,11]
```

My codes to compare a and b is something like this

```
b_list=[]
for x in range(len(a)):
    b_list.append(sum[i for i, j in zip(a, b) if i == j])
print(b_list)
```

`b should return 1 count and c should return 0 count I want the return to be something like this`

```
b = 1 , c = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
b_count, c_count = 0, 0
a = [11,22]
b = [33,22]
c = [22,11]

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == b[i]:
        b_count += 1
    if a[i] == c[i]:
        c_count += 1
print("b=", b_count, "c=", c_count)
```

if the lists are of variable size, you can use if condition to avoid index out of range error.

you can also use zip

```
b_count, c_count = 0, 0
a = [11,22]
b = [33,22]
c = [22,11]

for i in zip(a, b, c):
    if len(i) > 1 and i[0] == i[1]:
        b_count += 1
    if len(i) > 2 and i[0] == i[2]:
        c_count += 1
print("b=", b_count, "c=", c_count)
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `zip` for the iteration, rather than indexing all three lists.

Comment: It can be done using many number of ways in python but, why I use the for iteration is to make the logic clear for the person who read my post. is zip efficient than for loop under this condition, if so can you explain.

Comment: I'd unpack the tuple you get from `zip` right in the loop statement (`for a_item, b_item, c_item in zip(a, b, c):`). With that change, I feel like the whole loop becomes clearer, and legibility is more important than any performance impact (which should be minimal). Code that uses indexing can be doing more complicated stuff (like comparing `a[i]` with `b[i+1]` instead of `a[i]` with `b[i]`) so you have to read the code more carefully to be sure you know what is going on. I didn't downvote by the way, I thought your answer was just fine even without the small improvement from using `zip`.